# How to prevent users from installing Extensions in Google Chrome without admin privilege?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I(as admin) prevent other users from installing extensions in google chrome?

Comment: how to prevent users to install chrome... everyone is free to install any sntich they want

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Use --disable-extensions

You can run chrome/chromium with `--disable-extensions` switch

As **admin**, you can use a *wrapper script* calling the real chrome/chromium. but that could easily be worked-around, unless you compile that hard-coded into the binary if it is even possible.

## 2. Make Extensions folder read-only

You can disable write in `Extensions` folder of chrome/chromium in **the user's $HOME**

```
chmod 444 /home/theuser/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions
```

But nothing can prevent her/him from changing that back to writeable. So you can make it owned by root too

```
chown root.root /home/theuser/.config/chromium/Default/Extension
```

Comment: Since the OP is talking about _other_ users, `~` may be misleading.

Comment: @danzel ok. I have updated the answer