# chrome popups / malware

Tags: google-chrome, malware

I've got a school lab with Ubuntu 18. On some computers, when Chrome is open I'm getting popups saying things like "local weather" or "Sandra transferred $99,999.00 PayPal" and the like.

`chrome://extensions` is blank

I need to a) remove the malware / extension and b) somehow lock down the ability to modify Chrome ?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

There are several extensions for Chrome that block popups. [Poper Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pop-up-blocker-for-chrome/bkkbcggnhapdmkeljlodobbkopceiche?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) popup blocker for Chrome is one of them. Also refer to [How to prevent users from installing extensions in Google Chrome without admin privilege?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145514/).

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is [Malwarebytes Browser Guard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/malwarebytes-browser-guar/ihcjicgdanjaechkgeegckofjjedodee?hl=en) extension for Firefox and Chrome. It keeps an eye on popups, ads, trackers, malware, scams and PUPs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the popups were Chrome notification popups. Removing some websites from allowed popup sites fixed the problem.